# How does maven allow the $MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml to override the project local param -s settings.xml?

Tags: maven, settings

In general when working with [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) projects there are [properties](https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html) in the default version of the `settings.xml` which I'll call `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml`. An example might be

```
<settings>
  [...]
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>https://server1/</sonar.host.url>
```

Here the key-value of the property is:

```
key: sonar.host.url
property: https://server1/
```

You can also have a project-local version of the maven `settings.xml`. In this file is the contents:

```
      <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>https://server2/</sonar.host.url>
```

Here the key-value of the property is:

```
key: sonar.host.url
property: https://server2/
```

If you pass no parameters to the maven build - then it takes the `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` settings by default. eg

```
mvn compile
```

This will use

```
        <sonar.host.url>https://server1/</sonar.host.url>
```

I had expected that if you pass a project-local settings file ie `-s settings.xml` then it would ***always override the default maven settings*** in `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` ie running

```
mvn -s settings.xml compile
```

would ways use

```
        <sonar.host.url>https://server2/</sonar.host.url>
```

Today I saw the opposite and was trying to work out why.  Today I saw running

```
mvn -s settings.xml compile
```

always used the value

```
        <sonar.host.url>https://server1/</sonar.host.url>
```

ie the value in the default `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` file over the project-local `settings.xml` file.

To test this - I then went and deleted the value

```
        <sonar.host.url>https://server1/</sonar.host.url>
```

from the default version of the `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` - and then ***it changed***. After I deleted that row from the default `settings.xml` it started using

```
        <sonar.host.url>https://server2/</sonar.host.url>
```

My question is: **How does maven allow the `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` to override the project-local param `-s settings.xml` ?**

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you do not add or change anything in `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml`.

Instead, you use a `settings.xml` file in the user directory and then `.m2/settings.xml`.

I guess that your "strange" behaviour goes away if you do that.